# TFS build definition and relative workspace path

Tags: msbuild

Assuming this folder structure in the TFS 2010

```
Main
    Collection_A
        Solution_A1
        Solution_A2
        Reference Assemblies
    Collection_B
        Solution_B1
            Project_B1A
```

`Project_B1A` references the dll in `Reference Assemblies` of `Collection_A` by using relative path (`..\..\..\Collection_A\Reference Assemblies\Whatever.dll`). When defining the build definition in TFS, we are having trouble in the the Workflow tab.

```
Project_B1A => $(SourceDir)
```

for Reference Assemblies it should be

```
Reference Assemblies => $(SourceDir)\..\..\..\Collection_A\Reference Assemblies
```

but then TFS throws error

```
TF215083: The local path $(SourceDir)\..\..\Collection_A\Reference Assemblies for a 
workspace mapping is not valid. (Detail Message: TF10202: The path '..' ends with a 
character which is not allowed. Characters which are not allowed include '.' and ' '.)
```

We have tried `$(SourceDir)\Collection_A\Reference Assemblies` and `$(BuildDir)\Collection_A\Reference Assemblies` but as expected none worked. Are there any other variable that could be used?

Comment: Very well written question! However I think you meant "Workspace" tab, not "Workflow".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message indicates, I don't think using relative path is allowed when defining the working folder mappings.

What you should do instead is to start the mapping from the most common path of all possible paths you want to map (in this case, it's Main). So $(SourceDir) should be mapped to Main. However, you should map only the top level of Main (by using the asterisk as Main/*). This means you don't want to map Main recursively. Then you specify the specific sub folders of Main in other mappings.

It would look something like:

```
$/Main/* -> $(SourceDir)
$/Main/Collection_A/Reference Assemblies -> $(SourceDir)\Collection_A\Reference Assemblies
$/Main/Collection_B/Solution_B1/Project_B1A -> $(SourceDir)Collection_B\Solution_B1\Project_B1A
```

Alternatively, if the number of paths you don't want to map is less than the number of paths you want to map under a root path, you can map the root path recursively, but selectively cloak the ones you don't need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Agree: +1. One note, I would not set your first line `$/Main/* -> $(SourceDir)` at all - just the following two, because this first line would result with downloading everything under `$/Main/`. Just setting the latter two should work as desired.

Comment: That could work, I didn't remember exactly if we need to have the first line. And thanks for clarifying that it downloads the files and folders under Main, just not recursively.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I ended up using the $(BuildDir) as the paths were getting too long. Also, as @pantelif commented, I did not have to map the Main.

Comment: Thanks, that also solved our problem at work. Thanks also to @pantelif for pointing out that the top folder entry by itself was not necessary.